# Inverted beta in MySQL

Tags: mysql, math, statistics, probability

I need to implement an inverted beta function in MySQL (similar to [Excel's BETAINV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828299)).

There is some related material is available on Wolfram MathWorld's [Beta Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaDistribution.html) page.

Any clues on where to start implementing this functionality in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, task done by moving inverted beta calculation to PHP and using code from [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=PHPExcel) package.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [cephes](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/) library, specifically `cprob.tgz`. Be warned that the licensing situation of that code seems to be unclear. The source code just says "free", which was a problem for [Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=287507) so apparently they got the author to relicense it under the GPL for them.