# BetaInv function in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

similarly to the question: [Inverted beta in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153960/inverted-beta-in-mysql) I need to use the **BetaInv** function inside a SQL Server stored procedure.

function is described here: [Excel's BETAINV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828299)

is anybody aware of anything similar in TSQL or would you wrap it in a CLR .NET managed SQL user defined function?

I really need to use it within the stored procedure and not as post executing code in the C# side after data has been retrieved with the stored procedure because I should keep all logic on the db server for better reuse.

can I assume that a .NET managed udf running in the SQL Server would perform as fast as a normal native TSQL function?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you will have to implement your own. CLR stored procedure seems the way to go.

Comment: @Michael, Excel does support it, we are unsure if we should write our own version in C# or buy a license of a Math library like Extreme Numerics, I did some tests and for the BetaDist function, Extreme Numerics version is about 15% faster than our manually written one and we should calculate this for thousand records... I think either way I will create a CLR .NET stored proc which executes our c# code eventually calling Extreme Numerics.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. I've had good luck with CLR sprocs in the past. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've in the end implemented the whole function myself, here the source code in case somebody needs it:

```
    public static class UDFs
    {
        private const int MAXIT = 100;
        private const double EPS = 0.0000003;
        private const double FPMIN = 1.0E-30;

        [SqlFunction(Name = "BetaInv", DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
        public static SqlDouble BetaInv(SqlDouble p, SqlDouble alpha, SqlDouble beta, SqlDouble A, SqlDouble B)
        {    
            return InverseBeta(p.Value, alpha.Value, beta.Value, A.Value, B.Value);
        }

        private static double InverseBeta(double p, double alpha, double beta, double A, double B)
        {
            double x = 0;
            double a = 0;
            double b = 1;
            double precision = Math.Pow(10, -6); // converge until there is 6 decimal places precision

            while ((b - a) > precision)
            {
                x = (a + b) / 2;

                if (IncompleteBetaFunction(x, alpha, beta) > p)
                {
                    b = x;
                }
                else
                {
                    a = x;
                }
            }

            if ((B > 0) && (A > 0))
            {
                x = x * (B - A) + A;
            }

            return x;
        }

        private static double IncompleteBetaFunction(double x, double a, double b)
        {
            double bt = 0;

            if (x <= 0.0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (x >= 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            bt = System.Math.Exp(Gammln(a + b) - Gammln(a) - Gammln(b) + a * System.Math.Log(x) + b * System.Math.Log(1.0 - x));

            if (x < ((a + 1.0) / (a + b + 2.0)))
            {
                // Use continued fraction directly.
                return (bt * betacf(a, b, x) / a);
            }
            else
            {
                // Use continued fraction after making the symmetry transformation.
                return (1.0 - bt * betacf(b, a, 1.0 - x) / b);
            }
        }

        private static double betacf(double a, double b, double x)
        {
            int m, m2;
            double aa, c, d, del, h, qab, qam, qap;

            qab = a + b; // These q’s will be used in factors that occur in the coe.cients (6.4.6).
            qap = a + 1.0;
            qam = a - 1.0;

            c = 1.0; // First step of Lentz’s method.

            d = 1.0 - qab * x / qap;

            if (System.Math.Abs(d) < FPMIN)
            {
                d = FPMIN;
            }

            d = 1.0 / d;
            h = d;

            for (m = 1; m <= MAXIT; ++m)
            {
                m2 = 2 * m;
                aa = m * (b - m) * x / ((qam + m2) * (a + m2));
                d = 1.0 + aa * d; //One step (the even one) of the recurrence.

                if (System.Math.Abs(d) < FPMIN)
                {
                    d = FPMIN;
                }

                c = 1.0 + aa / c;

                if (System.Math.Abs(c) < FPMIN)
                {
                    c = FPMIN;
                }

                d = 1.0 / d;
                h *= d * c;

                aa = -(a + m) * (qab + m) * x / ((a + m2) * (qap + m2));
                d = 1.0 + aa * d; // Next step of the recurrence (the odd one).

                if (System.Math.Abs(d) < FPMIN)
                {
                    d = FPMIN;
                }

                c = 1.0 + aa / c;

                if (System.Math.Abs(c) < FPMIN)
                {
                    c = FPMIN;
                }

                d = 1.0 / d;
                del = d * c;
                h *= del;

                if (System.Math.Abs(del - 1.0) < EPS)
                {
                    // Are we done?
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (m > MAXIT)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return h;
            }
        }

        public static double Gammln(double xx)
        {
            double x, y, tmp, ser;

            double[] cof = new double[] { 76.180091729471457, -86.505320329416776, 24.014098240830911, -1.231739572450155, 0.001208650973866179, -0.000005395239384953 };

            y = xx;
            x = xx;
            tmp = x + 5.5;
            tmp -= (x + 0.5) * System.Math.Log(tmp);

            ser = 1.0000000001900149;

            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; ++j)
            {
                y += 1;
                ser += cof[j] / y;
            }

            return -tmp + System.Math.Log(2.5066282746310007 * ser / x);
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see in the code, the SqlFunction is calling the InverseBeta private method which does the job using couple of other methods.

results are the same of Excel.BetaInv up to 5 or 6 digits after comma.

Comment: check also here where I've got some suggestions on how to improve the speed making the conf array static... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413891/net-math-calculation-performances